# My wordpress banner shifts to left side when i zoom out from 100% to lesser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

The banner is not coming in the center.This is a revolution slider plugin by which the banner is shown.When i zoom out from 100% to lesser it displays the banner left aligned. and i have checked almost every setting in revolution slider plugin.
Any suggestions to make it to center?

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgwLx.jpg)

Comment: please link the page or recreate the page in a codepen. A picture doesn't show me any of the code that is actually a part of the problem.

Comment: Zooming your browser will frequently break some CSS